# Describe all possible values for the uknowm x(sub i) so that the matrix equation is valid.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$4 \begin{pmatrix}  x_1  &   x_2     \end{pmatrix} + 2\begin{pmatrix}x_1  & 3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -6 & 18 \end{pmatrix}$

I understand I should form a matrix and probably have to do row reducing echelon form, but I have never augmented a matrix with variables instead of numbers.  Help please!

Edit:
With a hint using back substitution I got $4x_1 +2x_1=-6$ and $4x_2 +6=18$ .
Using back substitution $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=3$.

How would I do this with a matrix?

Comment: You can split this matrix equation into two linear equations: $$4x_1+2x_1 = -6,$$ and $$4x_2+6 = 18.$$

Comment: I don't know who told you this should be solved with matrices, but they are wrong. As Guangliang demonstrates, this is just two simple equations in one variable each. I don't even know that you are describing as "back substitution". There is no substitution necessary. All that matrices would accomplish is to make something that is close to trivial into a huge complicated mess.